# jQuery Not Working On WordPress Divi Theme Mobile View

Tags: jquery, wordpress, divi-theme

Good day, All!

I built a WordPress site using Elegant Theme's Divi theme. Everything went well, until I start working on the mobile view. One of my menu item named "Vehicle" has a class of "btn-vehicle". Now on the desktop view, everytime a user clicks on the menu-item Vehicle, a hidden section with an ID of "#vehicle-categories" shows up by using .slideToggle()

Here's my script:

```
jQuery(".btn-vehicle").click(function(e){
  jQuery("#ourdealerships").hide();
e.preventDefault();
jQuery("#vehicle-categories").slideToggle();
jQuery(".btn-vehicle").toggleClass("opened closed");
});
```

That code works well on desktop view. But if i adjust my browser's screen size to a mobile view, If I click on the hamburger, the menu shows up, and if I click on Vehicle, the menu just closes without showing the #vehicle-categories.

This is the desktop view. If I click Vehicle in the menu, this section will show up below.
[image]

This is the mobile view. If Vehicle is clicked, the whole menu hides and nothing happens after that.
[image: if Vehicle is clicked, "#vehicle-categories" must show up.]

[image]

Even console.log is not working on mobile view. I want to test jQuery by using console.log("test") every time Vehicle is clicked.

Can someone pls help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is solved by putting a delay to call the function that declares the jquery click actions

```
$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
       setupActions();
    }, 700);
});

function setupActions() {
    //do your actions here
}
```